# Definition of convex hulls via maximal sets of interior-disjoint simplices

Tags: convex-polytopes, planar-partitions

Let the ***simplex cover*** of a finite set  $\mathcal{P}\subset \mathbb{E}^n,\ n\,\le\, k:=\operatorname{card}(\mathcal{P})\,\lt\infty$ of points in Euclidean $n$-space of which no $n+1$ are co-hyperplanar, denote a maximal interior-disjoint set of $n$-simplices with every corner an element of $\mathcal{P}$.

> **Questions:**
>
> letting $\mathrm{H}_\Sigma$ denote the set of simplex-sides, that are ***not*** shared by two simplices,
>
> - is $\mathrm{H}_\Sigma$ an invariant after a change of the *simplex covers* of a fixed pointset $\mathcal{P}$?
> - is $\mathrm{H}_\Sigma$ identical to the set of facets of the convex hull $\mathrm{CH}(\mathcal{P})$?

The reason for asking is the idea to base the definition of geometric hulls of discrete pointsets on the simplex-faces that are not shared by simplices by certain "regular" simplex-coverings of a pointset, provided the set of those undhared sides is invariant among all admissible coverings.

As there seem to be different definitions of the convex hull of a finite set of points in Euclidean spaces, in this context it shall mean what convex hull algorithms of computational geometry determine, namely ***the set of faces that constitute to the boundary of the intersection of all closed half-spaces in which $\mathcal{P}$ is contained***.

Comment: Is $H_\Sigma$ really the set of simplex *facets* (a set of subsets of $\Bbb E^n$), or the union of these? In the former case, I think already the cube can be decomposed in several different ways into simplices. And just a minor note: in the latter case, you probably meant to ask whether $H_\Sigma$ is the *boundary* of the convex hull, as the union of the simplex facets is not convex (but the convex hull is).

Comment: @M.Winter thanks for the feedback; I have improved my question based on it. In one point I however disagree: the convex hull itself is the set of **boundary points** of the set of all closed half-spaces that contain $\mathcal{P}$ and, whereas that intersection is convex, it's boundary is not.

Comment: I see. It might be worthwhile to include your definition of convex hull into the question. I assumed [the one from Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull), that is, the convex hull as the smallest convex set containing these points.

Comment: @M.Winter thanks again for your valuable feedback!